# Angular 9 Ivy and Wishtack ReactiveComponentLoader

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, ivy

```
:4200/vendor.js:39633 ERROR Error: Component '<app-shared-hero-image>' not found.
    at componentNotFoundError (:4200/vendor.js:113712)
    at ReactiveComponentLoader._tryGetComponentType (:4200/vendor.js:113803)
    at ReactiveComponentLoader.<anonymous> (:4200/vendor.js:113769)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (:4200/vendor.js:280350)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (:4200/polyfills.js:377)
    at Object.onInvoke (:4200/vendor.js:71213)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (:4200/polyfills.js:376)
    at Zone.run (:4200/polyfills.js:136)
    at :4200/polyfills.js:870
```

I am having trouble to render my components with wishtack reactive component loader, it says that doesn't found my component but i really exist.

Comment: Can you show if AOT is enabled or module?

Comment: Try disabling ivy `"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }` in tsconfig.app.json